# webview Image preview before uploading. I want the user to preview the image

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a website that am trying to convert to android app using android studio, everything is working fine on the web, which user can preview image before sending it to server. After the website as been converted to android app the preview is not working on android...below is the code am running in android studio to convert the website...I will be very glad with any help and code...preview to work from API Level 15 to API level 28

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String websiteURL = "https://example.com"; // sets web url
    private WebView webview;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue
                        (WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null :
                    intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        if( ! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this)) //returns true if internet available
        {
            //if there is no internet do this
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection, Chris",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("You need an internet connection to use this app")
                    .setMessage("Check to see if you're mobile data is on or you are connected to a wi-fi network.")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    //.setNegativeButton("No", null)
                                    .show();
        }
        else
        {
            //Webview stuff
            webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
           webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

            webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());


            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
            {
                // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
                // onActivityResult attached before constructor
                protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
                {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                            FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }


                // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
                public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]>
                        filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
                {
                    if (uploadMessage != null) {
                        uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                        uploadMessage = null;
                    }

                    uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                    Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                    try
                    {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        uploadMessage = null;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //For Android 4.1 only
                protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String
                        acceptType, String capture)
                {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"),
                            FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }

                protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
                {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                            FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }
            });




        }


        //Swipe to refresh functionality
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webview.reload();
                    }
                }
        );

        //Progress bar variables
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
    }


    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
        }

    }
    private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }


    //set back button functionality
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { //if user presses the back button do this
        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) { //check if in webview and the user can go back
            webview.goBack(); //go back in webview
        } else { //do this if the webview cannot go back any further

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("You are about to close the application")
                    .setMessage("You cannot go back any further, would you like to close?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}


class CheckNetwork {
    private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();
    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(info.isConnected())
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```